# How can I convert a date that's in "yyyy-mm/dd" to "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that's called appt_date (varchar(50)) that's in the format of YYYY-MM/DD and I want to convert it to YYYY-MM-DD

I've tried several replace, convert, cast functions and solutions found on here but I still end up with the same result.

I greatly appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Show your attempt at what you've tried as a [mcve] and explain how it's not working for you.

Comment: maybe... select try_convert(date,replace('2021-12/25','/','-'))

Comment: Do you want to convert it to a `varchar` using the "format" `YYYY-MM-DD` (which as it's a `varchar` is by definition not a date and time) or do you *actually* want to fix your design and store the value in the proper data type? (Hint, you want to fix your design.)

Comment: Just replace the slash with a dash and CAST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will strongly suggest to change your data base design and never store data in text format.

You can try  and let me know if it helps:

```
  CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
  appt_date varchar(50) );

  insert into test_tbl 
  values ('2021-09/12'),
         ('2021-11/01'),
         ('2020-07/06');

 SELECT TRY_PARSE(appt_date as date ) as appt_date 
 FROM test_tbl;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b8a3b59b48aa51b5ff2eedccf8f12c15

More info on: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-functions-for-converting-string-to-date/

Comment: so my raw/source tables store everything as varchar and then I convert it to date in a "final" table we actually use. the issue I'm having is that one of the source tables has the appt date in yyyy-mm/dd format and the ETL script doesn't want to convert it to date.

Comment: @sqlrobert did you try the query i provided?

Comment: yes, thank you! @Ergest Basha